# Как правильно перебрать двумерный массив Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Как проверить, `board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2] .... board[0][j]`, на наличие или отсутствие 'x'?

Нужно чтобы одновременно все (`board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]... board[0][j]) ! == ' '`, тогда должно выводиться `console.log('Поехали')`. Сейчас получается если хотя бы один `board[0][j] ! == ' '`, то выводится консоль (нельзя использовать === 'x', вместо 'x' может быть другой символ).

```
let board = [
  ['','','x'],    //[0][0] [0][1]  [0][2]   это я пишу для себя элемент [0][2] = 'x'
  ['','',''],      //[1][0] [1][1]  [1][2]
  ['','','']       //[2][0] [2][1]  [2][2]
  ]

function enumeration (i, j) {
  for(let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
      if (board[i][0] !== '' && i++ || board[0][j] !== '' && j++) {
        console.log('Поехали');
      }
    }
  }
}
enumeration();
```

Comment: Крестики-Нолики?

Comment: Как много тегов для такого вопроса)) Подредачил чуть))

Comment: Здравствуйте! Александр пытаюсь разобраться, как написать крестики - нолики. Мне нравиться программирование, большая часть не получается, бросать не хочу. Не подскажите в чем ошибка в данном коде? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Я ничего не понял.

Comment: @АлександрБугаев если самый простой вариант - то вам нужно завести переменную с подсчётом элементов.. Инициализировать нулём. Далее в цикле в условии прописать увеличение счётчика... А уже **ЗА** циклом проверить, если число в счётчике совпадает с количеством элементов в массиве - значит везде пустота

Comment: `(arr) => arr.flat().every(e => e !== '')`

Comment: @АлександрБугаев а вот эту надпись "Поехали" вы хотите показывать в начале игры, когда ещё поле не заполнено?

Comment: Учитывая что я уже отвечал на этот вопрос, могу дать только ссылку для ознакомления https://stackoverflow.com/a/66961412/12915495 с рабочим вариантом. Там внизу и алгоритм нарисован картинкой.

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, проверка на выигрыш - заполнение по горизонтали, или вертикали, или диагонали (поле не должно быть заполнено). Честно говоря  я не понял Вашего вопроса.

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь, а  в особенности  Alexander Lonberg

Comment: @АлександрБугаев мы ваш вопрос тоже не все поняли :D  Я вот подумал, что ваш вопрос заключается в том, что как проверить, что все значения в массиве равны пустоте. И если все пустые - выводить в консоль "Поехали". А оказывается вон чего